# How to show $|E(X)| \leq E(|X|)$ for column vector $X$ of random variables

Tags: probability

Suppose $X=(X_1,X_2,...,X_d)^T$ is a column vector of random variables and $| \cdot |$ is the euclidean norm. Expectations are taken component-wise. Then how do we show:

$$|E(X)| \leq E(|X|) \quad ?$$

Many thanks for your help.

EDIT:

Following the hints below I have started by letting $X = \sum_{k=1}^d x_k 1_{A_k}$

where $x_k = (x_k^1,...,x_k^d) \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and where $A_k$ are *disjoint* measurable sets in the underlying probability space. By approximation this is sufficient.

The claim to prove is now:

$$\left( \sum_i \left( \sum_k x^i_k P(A_k) \right)^2 \right)^{1/2} \leq E \left( \left( \sum_{i,k} (x^i_k)^2 1_{A_k} \right)^{1/2} \right) .$$

By Jensen's inequality,

$$ RHS \geq  \sum_k P(A_k)  \left( \sum_i (x_k^i)^2\right)^{1/2}$$

and also

$$ LHS \leq \left( \sum_k P(A_k) \sum_i (x^i_k)^2 \right)^{1/2} .$$

But now Jensen is no good to conclude, as it's "the wrong way round" to take the square root inside in the estimate of the LHS.

Many thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: How do you show $|\int{f}| \leq \int{|f|}$ ?

Comment: the problem I have is the involvement of the euclidean norm. obviously for real valued random variables it's easy.

Comment: It is a special case of Jensen's inequality.  Google around and you should find something.

Comment: I have edited the question with my attempt that uses your hints, but I am afraid I still can't get the answer. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the triangle inequality and positive homogeneity, the Euclidean-norm, $\|\ \|:C\to\mathbb R$, is convex (where $C\subseteq \mathbb R^d$ is a convex set). That is, for $\lambda\in[0,1]$ and $x,y\in C$,
$$
\|\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y\|\leqslant \lambda \|x\|+(1-\lambda)\|y\|\ .
$$

As a consequence, there exists a linear real-valued map, $l:C\to\mathbb R$, such that

1. $l(x)\leqslant\|x\|$ for all $x\in C$;
2. $l(\mathbb E[X])=\|\mathbb E[X]\|$ for integrable $d$-dimensional random vector $X$.

Therefore,
$$
\| \mathbb E[X] \| = l(\mathbb E[X]) = (\mathbb E[l(X)]) \leqslant \mathbb E[\| X \|]\ .
$$

As hinted in the comments, this is simply an application of Jensen's inequality.

Comment: and, as I understand it, an application of the Hahn-Banach theorem...? this is the bit I didnt think of.

Comment: @Frank, ...correct. In particular, I rely on the supporting hyperplane theorem (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supporting_hyperplane) applied to the epigraph of $\|\ \|$. In fact, with a few cosmetic tweaks, the response above is really a proof of Jensen's inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that for $x\in \mathbb R^d$, $\|x\|=\sup\{|f(x)|: f\in (\mathbb R^d)^* \text{ and } \|f\|_*\leq 1\}$ where $(\mathbb R^d)^*$ is the topological dual and $\|\cdot\|_*$ is the dual norm.

Note also that if $x\in \mathbb R^d$ and $f\in (\mathbb R^d)^*$,
$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^d x_i f(e_i)$.

Thus $\|E[X]\|= \sup\{|f(E[X])|: f\in (\mathbb R^d)^* \text{ and } \|f\|_*\leq 1\}$.
Next, fix some $f\in (\mathbb R^d)^*$ with $\|f\|_*\leq 1$ and note that
$|f(E[X])| = |\sum_{i=1}^d E[X_i] f(e_i)|=|E[\sum_{i=1}^d X_i f(e_i)]| = |E[f(X)]|\leq E[|f(X)|]\leq E[\|X\|]$ where the last inequality follows from
$\|f\|_*\leq 1$.

Taking the supremum yields the claim.