# $||E[X]|| \leq E[||X||]$

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, inequality

Let $X$ be a r.v. taking values in $\mathbb{R}^d,$ such that $X \in L^1.$ $||.||$ is an arbitrary norm on $\mathbb{R}^d.$ Prove that $$||E[X]||\leq E[||X||].$$

When $d=1,$ then letting $\theta=\frac{E[X]}{|E[X]|},$ $|E[X]|=\frac{1}{\theta}E[X] \leq E[\frac{1}{|\theta|}|X|]\leq E [|X|].$

Having problems with $d>1,$ what do suggest to do? Is there a way to prove it using the above argument?

Comment: Isn't this just the fact that $|\int f| \leq \int |f|$ for any function $f$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1191734/66096.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that for $x\in \mathbb R^d$, $\|x\|=\sup\{|f(x)|: f\in (\mathbb R^d)^* \text{ and } \|f\|_*\leq 1\}$ where $(\mathbb R^d)^*$ is the topological dual and $\|\cdot\|_*$ is the dual norm.

Note also that if $x\in \mathbb R^d$ and $f\in (\mathbb R^d)^*$,
$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^d x_i f(e_i)$.

Thus $\|E[X]\|= \sup\{|f(E[X])|: f\in (\mathbb R^d)^* \text{ and } \|f\|_*\leq 1\}$.
Next, fix some $f\in (\mathbb R^d)^*$ with $\|f\|_*\leq 1$ and note that
$|f(E[X])| = |\sum_{i=1}^d E[X_i] f(e_i)|=|E[\sum_{i=1}^d X_i f(e_i)]| = |E[f(X)]|\leq E[|f(X)|]\leq E[\|X\|]$ where the last inequality follows from
$\|f\|_*\leq 1$.

Taking the supremum yields the claim.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If you want to prove this statement - you'll have to prove 2 fairly easy things: (a) that norms are convex functions and (b) jensen's inequality for convex functions.
Both proofs are very fun - esp. when you arrive at them by yourself, but also easily google-able.